# Only reading certain lines of data from .arff file into struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, file-io

I have a .arff file that looks like this

```
% Title: Database for fitting contact lenses
% 
% Number of Instances: 24
% 
% Number of Attributes: 4 (all nominal)
% 
% Attribute Information -- 3 Classes:
%   1 : the patient should be fitted with hard contact lenses,
%   2 : the patient should be fitted with soft contact lenses,
%   3 : the patient should not be fitted with contact lenses.
%  
% Class Distribution:
%    1. hard contact lenses: 4
%    2. soft contact lenses: 5
%    3. no contact lenses: 15

@relation contact-lenses

@attribute age          {young, pre-presbyopic, presbyopic}
@attribute spectacle-prescrip   {myope, hypermetrope}
@attribute astigmatism      {no, yes}
@attribute tear-prod-rate   {reduced, normal}
@attribute contact-lenses   {soft, hard, none}

@data
%
% 24 instances
%
young,myope,no,reduced,none
young,myope,no,normal,soft
young,myope,yes,reduced,none
young,myope,yes,normal,hard
young,hypermetrope,no,reduced,none
young,hypermetrope,no,normal,soft
young,hypermetrope,yes,reduced,none
young,hypermetrope,yes,normal,hard
pre-presbyopic,myope,no,reduced,none
pre-presbyopic,myope,no,normal,soft
pre-presbyopic,myope,yes,reduced,none
pre-presbyopic,myope,yes,normal,hard
pre-presbyopic,hypermetrope,no,reduced,none
pre-presbyopic,hypermetrope,no,normal,soft
pre-presbyopic,hypermetrope,yes,reduced,none
pre-presbyopic,hypermetrope,yes,normal,none
presbyopic,myope,no,reduced,none
presbyopic,myope,no,normal,none
presbyopic,myope,yes,reduced,none
presbyopic,myope,yes,normal,hard
presbyopic,hypermetrope,no,reduced,none
presbyopic,hypermetrope,no,normal,soft
presbyopic,hypermetrope,yes,reduced,none
presbyopic,hypermetrope,yes,normal,none
```

and I only want to read the lines that have data on them such as

```
young,myope,no,reduced,none
young,myope,no,normal,soft
young,myope,yes,reduced,none
```

into a struct. The struct has a string member for each of the 5 pieces of data. How can I write a loop, or combination of loops, to skip the lines I am not concerned about, and read the data I am looking for into the struct?

Edit: I only want to read a line that does not start with %, @, or a blank line. I do not understand why this doesn't work.

```
while(inFile.good())
{
    getline(inFile,line);

    if((line[0] == '%') || (line[0] == '@') || (line[0] == ' '))
    {
        cout << "This line we dont care about" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Made it into the else" << endl;
        getline(inFile,line,',');
        data[count].age = line;
        cout << "data[0] = " << data[count].age << endl;
        getline(inFile,line,',');
        data[count].prescription = line;
        cout << "data[0] = " << data[count].prescription << endl;
        getline(inFile,line,',');
        data[count].astig = line;
        getline(inFile,line,',');
        data[count].tearProduction = line;
        getline(inFile,line);
        data[count].contacts = line;

        count++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend researching "lexing" and "parsing".  You may need to have the data sheet or requirements on the file format to find out where your "data" lines begin.  Worst case, read a line, and if it's not what you want, ignore it and read the next line.

Comment: Basically I want to read in any line that doesn't start with @, %, or a blank line. Is there anyway to check for that?

Comment: Yes, read the line using `std::getline` into a `std::string` and check the first character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am trying that, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have edited my question with the code I am using, will you please take a look?

Comment: One issue with your code is that if the line is empty, then `line[0]` will be undefined.  You'll need to check the length first.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Your code works much better than mine did, but I think it is also not skipping the empty lines. I printed out the lines of data with a number on the end for their count, and I am getting too many lines now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample to get you started:

```
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(my_data_file, text_line)
{
  // Check the line length first.  Empty lines are ignored.
  if (text_line.length() == 0)
  {
    continue;
  }

  // Test lines for rejection by reading the first character.
  const char c = text_line[0];
  if ((c == '@') || (c == '%') || (c == ' '))
  {
    continue;
  }
  // Add code to parse the data lines
}
```

The `continue` will cause execution to go to the top of the `while` loop, thus ignoring the line.

Comment: I used this code to give it a test run, and it works almost perfectly. For some reason before the data starts, it prints 3 blank lines. Do you happen to know why? Edit: It also chops off the first letter of the line, so it would print out oung instead of young

Comment: None of the code posted above modifies the `text_line`.  You output depends on where you put the `cout`.  The first character could be a tab or other whitespace as well as non-printing control character.

Comment: It seemed to be a weird printing error. Do you happen to know why the blank lines are still printing? Or how could I parse the lines of data to just put each string (separated by a comma) into a struct?

Comment: For parsing into a struct, search the internet for "StackOverflow c++ read file struct comma separated".